# force to stop animation of particular div

Tags: jquery

I'm using a [plugin for image scroll](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/rotators/images-rotators/8742) which is scrolling the image but this time I have to cancel that animation whatsoever is appplied by that plugin. So I tried this

```
$('#banner-footer').find('*').stop(true, true);
```

But also not working. Any idea?

it's producing

```
element.style {
    left: -79px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: What plugin are you using for the image scroll?

Comment: Can you provide a link, I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Can you please reproduce a simple demo of what's happening, with your HTML and jQuery? With what you've posted we can only take guesses (and probably close as not a real question).

Comment: I've updated the link in question.

Comment: You can see [live site](http://nepotech.com/kldugar/)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
$('#banner-footer').find('*').each(function(){
  $(this).stop(true, true);
});
```

I'm not sure if you can call .stop() on an array of elements.

Comment: `.stop()` iterates through the collection behind the scenes.